# Is there a shortcut to open the directory where Xcode installs apps on the simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I thought I came across a menu item or a right-click command akin to "Open app bundle location in Finder" but I can't find it.  Maybe it was a secret wish in during dream.  Maybe not.  Does this exist?

EDIT: I know where these files live in the file system.  I've added the iPhone Simulator folder to the dock in order to make it easy to get there.  I'm doing a lot of work where I have to verify that the app bundle got updated as necessary.  As I said, I thought I had seen a right-click menu that could get you there faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if there is such a shortcut, but you definitely can browser through your files by going to :

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

Comment: Right, that's not a problem.  I thought I saw a right-click command to get there quickly.  For now I just added it to the dock so that it is convenient.  Edited original question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SimPholders 1.5](http://simpholders.com). From their website:

> A small utility for fast access to your iPhone Simulator apps. Opens
>   folder in Finder, resets library and documents, and deletes the
>   selected app.